# Numba.jit() built in function to make our performance faster in python

Tags: python

can anyone give one example to clarify it.Thanks!

I would like to know before I imply it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/this-decorator-will-make-python-30-times-faster-715ca5a66d5f).
Instead of doing operation with numpy array or pandas you can do the following

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def add_arrays(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Instead of

```
def add_arrays(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Of course there are more applications and uses of njit and numba in general but this is the one I've found my self using most of the times.